# Laravel Policy - check status of entity

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I am having a model with a `status` attribute (which can be `open` or `ready`). The model can be edited when the status is `open`, but should be blocked when its `ready`.

Am I 'allowed' to do this in my `Policy`? Or are policies only meant for authorisation stuff?

I know I can just do this, my question is more about principles within Laravel...

Answer (score 1):

It think there is nothing wrong with putting this kind of check in the Policy of your model, it depends a bit on the context. I'd like to think of Policies (as you described) as initial entry gate into a given application. So if it's for example only relevant within the update method of your Controller, you are fine imho.

However, in case there might be others "paths" or processes that might be affected by the "open/ready" constraint you described it could also be reasonable to put this kind of checks in the `ModelObserver saving` method.

By doing this you make sure that you are not accidentally manipulating the object when it's `ready` just because you forgot to do the authorization check upfront. In other words by implementing it in the `saving` method of the ObserverClass you have a "self-contained" bit of behaviour that rather represents business logic than authorization logic.

Comment: Thank you for your useful reply @mynd. Since I want to keep some flexibility in my core (events, jobs, et cetera) using the Policy feelds good to me. In my Policy I could refer to a Manager (which is part of my business logic).